# Does Ribbon go through all Eurkea registered instances before hystrix calls the fallback?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Suppose I have 2 micro service instances of the same name/type registered with Eureka and Ribbon is load balancing between them.  I also have configured a Hystrix fallback in case the services are down.  Will Ribbon attempt to contact all available services supporting the endpoint URL before the Hystrix fallback is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your configuration.

Usually Hystrix fallback will be executed by any following conditions.

- Any exception thrown by your code that is being executed by HystrixCommand (except `HystrixBadRequestException`)
- Hystrix timeout
- Hystrix ThreadPool/Semaphore Rejection
- Hystrix circuit open

Hystrix doesn't prevent Ribbon retrying during Hystrix's timeout. If timeout reaches, Hystrix will execute fallback method after interrupting user's code.

Ribbon's retry can be adjusted with the following properties.

- `ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer`
- `ribbon.MaxAutoRetries`
- `ribbon.ReadTimeout`
- `ribbon.ConnectTimeout`

Therefore, your fallback will be called

- just after all ribbon's retrying are failed if they are ended in Hystrix's timeout
- Or, just after Hystrix's timeout if Ribbon's all retrying operation is not ended until Hystrix' timeout.